# Grid-based UICollectionView on iOS 8 (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to implement a `UICollectionView` that's grid-based, so that it looks something like this where every box is either a square or a rectangle. The number of items per row and the dimensions of each cell would differ based on screen size (i.e. iPhone 4, 5S, 6, iPad, etc.). This can be done using JavaScript: http://packery.metafizzy.co/ but I'd like to figure out how to do it using Swift. This would only need to work with iOS 8+ so I'm not sure if the native `UICollectionView` can do this already. Should I be implementing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No native `Layouts` will not provide this functionality.You have to extend `UICollectionViewLayout` and make custom `Layout` based on that

You can look this [example](https://github.com/SureCase/WaterfallCollectionView) and this [example](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout).It will help you.However it is in objective-c

Comment: Thanks, `RFQuiltLayout` looks interesting. I'll take a look and get back to you.